# How to read files with spaces in name using R?

Tags: r, xml, filenames

I am trying to write a script to process thousands of xml files that have spaces in the filename using R but am getting an error when I try to test reading the first file. The error I get says the file does not exist. I am using the xml2 package.

I tried google searching but couldn't find a solution as I need to read in the files with spaces in the name. the solutions I came across were to rename file or were for folder names with spaces.

Since my xml files are in multiple folders (some with spaces in folder names), I am dynamically generating the folder and file pathways using `list.files()` and concatenating the root using `paste()` to get the full pathways to the xml files.

This is the code I am trying on my first file (without concatenating pathway):

```
read_xml('/Users/bob_ross/Desktop/test file with spaces.xml')
```

In Python I would be able to use a raw string but when I try that in R:

```
read_xml(r"(/Users/bob_ross/Desktop/test file with spaces.xml)")
```

I get the same error:

> Error: '/Users/bob_ross/Desktop/test file with spaces.xml' does not exist.

Does anyone know a way to read filenames with spaces with R? or is it best to do this in Python?

Comment: Which `read_xml` function are you using?  That's not in any base packages.  Maybe use `readLines()` to read the file, then pass it to `read_xml`?

Comment: Files with spaces should be fine in R. E.g. `readLines("test file.txt")` just worked for me. Maybe try using TAB-completion to make sure there isn't something strange with the filename, e.g. type `"/Users/` and hit TAB and keep typing bits until you get the full string, then compare it with your string you are currently entering.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with spaces.

Comment: can you test it for a file *without* spaces in the title? Is it possible that the spaces are some weird alternative space-like character? `library(xml2); file.create("file with blanks.xml"); read_xml("file with blanks.xml")` gives an error about the file being empty (*not* about it not existing).. What does `file.exists("file with blanks.xml")` (or equivalent) return?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. It turns out there was an issue with the filepath and the suggestion by @BenBolker to run file.exists() helped solve the issue. Feeling a bit silly I didnt check that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue does not appear to be spaces.

I saved a a xml file with a space and was able to make it work.  I am assuming you are using package:"xml2"
I was able to retrieve and assign the file to the environment and then recall it.

```
> library(xml2)
> doc <- read_xml('/Users/kevinwilliams/Downloads/note 1.xml')
> doc
{xml_document}
<note>
[1] <to>Tove</to>
[2] <from>Jani</from>
[3] <heading>Reminder</heading>
[4] <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
```